# In Visual Studio can one find all types derived from a specific type, e.g. from ActionResult

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In the Visual Studio object browser, one can expand a type, e.g. `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`, and see that it is derived from `ActionResult`.

Is there a way to go to the parent type and see all objects derived from it?